# How to get the initials of a name in Russian - PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I've got a question about handling Russian characters in order to render the initials.

1) My html doc has utf-8 declared:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

2) My name field in my MySQL db is:

```
utf8_unicode_ci
```

3) When I query the name of a user called:

```
Богдан Доминика
```

A var_dump gives:

```
string(23) "Ð”Ð°Ñ€ÑŒÑ Ð ÑÐ±Ð¾Ð²Ð°"
```

4) When I do this:

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($name)
```

I get:

```
UTF-8
```

5) The user sees this on the front end (which is right):

```
Богдан Доминика
```

**What I want:**

6) But I want to get the initials of the name and print them out. If I do this (cut down version):

```
$initials = substr($first_name, 0, 1) . substr($second_name, 0, 1)
```

7) I get this on the front end:

```
�Р
```

8) If I take the first two chars of first and second name I get the result I want:

```
БД
```

**Question:**

How can I determine that the string in 3) is Russian (or any other character set)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use PHP's multi-byte functions... such as `mb_substr` https://www.php.net/mb_substr

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a bug to detect Russian encodings. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38138

**Excerpt:**

> Detection of russian encoding in mb_detect_encoding is disabled
>   although it present among the list of supported encodings. It just
>   three rather simple encodings - windows-1251, cp866 and koi8-r that
>   spoil everyday life routines of russian programmer and make PHP less
>   attractive for millions of potential PHP developers.

You might want to use a different function such as [mb_substr()](http://php.net/mb_substr) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Russian is a language, not a character set. Unicode (encoded in UTF-8) contains characters for all the world languages and is the only character set you should ever use. Language-specific character sets, such as ISO-8859-1 for English and European languages with diacritical marks (such as German, French and Swedish) and ISO-8859-5 for Cyrillic are legacy extensions of ASCII that are restricted to a specific script. Using Unicode (through UTF-8) allows your script to support all possible characters.

If you're using Unicode correctly, **the language and script of the text that you're processing becomes irrelevant**. That means that if you're using the multibyte extensions (those functions that start with `mb_`) correctly, there is *no need to worry* about the language that you're processing.

But let's move on to your specific problem. First of all, use the `Content-Type` HTTP header to set the correct encoding instead of a `meta` tag. Add the following to the beginning of your script and remove the `meta` tag:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

This should also fix the `var_dump` output.

Next, to get the initials of a full name, you'll want to do the following:

1. Split the name to get the first and last name.
2. Get the first letter of each element.
3. Combine the letters to get the initials.

Try this example:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $full_name = $_POST['name'];

    // split the name on whitespace, this includes Unicode characters
    // that represent whitespace but are not 0x20 (ASCII space)
    $elements = preg_split('/\s+/', $full_name);

    // get the initials
    $initials = '';
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        $initials .= mb_substr($element, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
    }

    echo "<p>Your initials are: ", $initials, "</p>\n";
}

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <p>
        Please enter your name:
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

I've put up a demo for you at https://peschar.net/files/initials.php.